# How to render a html string content in PDF using JsPDF in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, pdf-generation, jspdf

I need to show a PDF with the HTML string available. I am using JsPDF for this. I used to get a dynamic content as string. The received string will be a html content. This needs to be formatted and show in a PDF.

I used the below command to install JsPDF

```
npm i jspdf --save
```

And I initialised the library and provided the content. Calling save downloads the file.

```
var doc = new jsPDF()
doc.text('<html></head> Title </head><body> Content </body></html>', 10, 10)
doc.save('a4.pdf')
```

This prints the text as it is. I need to show that as formatted html. Also it is good it it opens in new tab rather than downloading.

Thanks.

Comment: `jsPDF` is a PDF generator, but you'll need a PDF viewer to view the document. Take a look at: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

Answer (score 0):

```
  onPrint = () => {
    const {post} = this.state;

    let pdfConverter = jspdf,
      doc = new pdfConverter();

    stringHtml = `<div>${post}</div>`;

    doc.setFontSize(22);
    doc.text('Title', 15, 15);
    doc.fromHTML(stringHtml, 15, 20, {'width': 180});

    window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank');
  };
```

disable AdBlock